# How Do I Pass the Multiple Line Form Data to The Array? The form is not passing the string in the array

Tags: php, html, forms, api

This is the simple form where i can put multiple lines

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="domains">
     <textarea name="message" rows="" cols="" name="domains" ></textarea>
      <br></br>
      <input type="submit"> <br></br>
    <br></br>
    </form>
```

Php code:

```
<?PHP
$domains= $_POST['domains'];

$url = 'the API url';
```

This is the confusing part. How do i put those multi-line form data to this array?

```
$query = http_build_query(array(
        'domains' => array(
            $domain = explode("\n",$string)
        )
    ));
$url = $url .'?'. $query;
$ch = curl_init();
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
$headers = ['API-OPR: apikey '];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $output; 
curl_close ($ch);
$output = json_decode($output,true);
?>
```

Comment: Explode `$domains` by newline or space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode `$domains` by newline to make it array to work

```
$domains=  explode("\n",$_POST['domains']);
```

Sample example: https://3v4l.org/DFAuT